# How to fill color inside Circle SeekBar

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glqrW.png)

I'd like to fill in the current value at circle seekbar (above picture blue part)

What should i do?

Comment: Bro give some screenshots and more detail about what you are trying to achieve and where are you facing the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.